# Chrome_Options Argument Check

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

```
 try:
            proxy = proxy_generator()
             ua =  user_agent_rotator.get_random_user_agent()
            chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
            chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxy))
            chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent='.format(ua))
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path='C:/Users/mypc/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(5)

            page_html = driver.page_source

            driver.quit()
            page_soup = soup(page_html,features="html5lib")
            Product_Title = 
            page_soup.find("div{"class":"ProductMainSection__productName"}).get_text().strip()

            break
        except:

            pass
```

I am trying to get the page_html code but its quite Not working .. I guess its not updating the Ip Address and User-Agents since all this code is in a loop. Can some one tell me how can  i check the arguments value being pass to the driver on run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to see the passed arguments is to start the driver in non-headless mode. Then go to `chrome://version`

Also you are missing the curly brackets in your user agent string formatting. That means the user agent will be passed as blank, and chrome will use the default.

Try:
`chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent={}".format(ua))`